# How to wire a double wall light

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

I would like to install a double wall light where I'm told there used to be one previously. However, the wires in the wall and the wires of the light are both confusing me, and I'm not sure the best way to connect everything up. I have wired lights to a wall before, but it was a simple live to live, neutral to neutral etc., and this has a lot more going on. This question is in two parts.

Firstly, the double wall light arrived with the wires arranged like so:

[image: Close up of wires]

There is a live and a neutral wire running along the arm of each light, and a single earth wire. The wires have already come twisted together like this:

[image: Wire Ends]

**Is this correct?** Should the live and neutral for each light be twisted together? Or should both the lives be twisted together and both the neutrals be twisted together?

Secondly, this is the state of the wires coming out of the wall:

[image] [image]

It looks as though a cable has been cut, and then both lives twisted together, both neutrals twisted together, and both earths twisted together, to allow the wires of a light to be attached. My second question is, **do I leave these twisted together when I install the wall light?** Do these need altering at all for installing a double wall light?

Since the wall is in a bit of a state from the previous owner I am considering hiring a professional for this one, but wanted to have a go myself first. If someone could tell me just how the wires should be for this installation I'd be very grateful, I can't really find any diagrams of how to do it online through Googling. I can provide any extra info if requested.

Comment: the fixture wires should be attached to the same colored wire (ie blue to blue and brown to brown).  Not sure but i'd guess blue is positive (Hot) and brown neutral. If so attach blue wires to Red (hot) wall wire and browns (neutral to  neutral wall wire. Green to ground (earth).

Comment: Was this lamp either a) locally sourced at a bricks-n-mortar shop, and CE stamped.... or b) mail ordered (which means CE is worthless) but with a competent testing lab's label (BSI, TUV, etc.)?  Because the wires were pre-twisted like that for the builder's ease of assembly, and should not be wired that way... seems kinda sloppy on their part.

Comment: @Harper Option b) mail ordered, although what you say makes a lot of sense, assembly of the light would seem to be easier with both wires twisted together for feeding them down the arms of the lamp.

Answer (score 3):

Well you have 1 circuit in and one out (or a ring) to connect the light connect both browns to the reds, both blues to the neutrals and the green yellow to the earth. This should get you hooked up correctly.

Comment: So I should untwist the wires of the light as they've already come, and twist both lives and both neutrals together?

Comment: They should be clamped to a terminal block, my side of the pond a wire nut would work on your side a Wego or a lever lock with enough ports 1 for each wire. The white block looks like it was set up for 2 on each terminal if they fit I would go with that but we have different rules so I am not sure if that is proper but appears to be what was done before.

Comment: @EdBeal-your answer is saying to attach browns to reds and browns to the neutral. Shouldn't be Blues to neutral?

Comment: Oops I meant blues must have had a brain fart while typing.